# Deserilize array of objects in GSon

Tags: java, json, api, gson

Greetins fellow coders!
I have searched the forums but can't seem to be able to find the answers I need. I am an android app beginner so could greatly use some help! 
I have an API that I fetch from the server and I am trying to deserialize it (using GSon) and populate my list view with it. My app downloads the API but for some reason it returns gson as null as I try to deserialize it.
I have created a class of getters (Company.java), the response to it (Response.java)-[not sure if its structured correctly] and I call LoadJsonTask.java in my MainActivity. 
Can anyone give me some pointers? I would highly appreciate that!
(sorry there is so much code but wanted to make my problem easy to understand :) )
Thanks you!

Here's my code:
Company class:

```
public class Company {
private String id;
private String name;
private String phone;
private String address;
private String postcode;
private String gps_lat;
private String gps_lng;
private String summary;
private String website;
private String facebook;
private String twitter;
private String webform;
private String email;

public String getId(){
    return id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public String getPostcode() {
    return postcode;
}

public String getGps_lat() {
    return gps_lat;
}

public String getGps_lng(){
    return gps_lng;
}

public String getSummary(){
    return summary;
}

public String getWebsite(){
    return website;
}

public String getFacebook(){
    return facebook;
}

public String getTwitter(){
    return twitter;
}

public String getWebform(){
    return webform;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}
}
```

My Response class:
    public class Response {

```
private List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<Company>();

public List<Company> getCompanies() {
    return companies;
}
}
```

Load JSonTask:

```
public class LoadJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Response> {

public LoadJSONTask(Listener listener) {

    mListener = listener;
}

public interface Listener {

    void onLoaded(List<Company> androidList);

    void onError();
}

private Listener mListener;

@Override
protected Response doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {

        String stringResponse = loadJSON(strings[0]);

        List<Company> android = new Gson().fromJson(stringResponse, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Company>>(){}.getType());
        return android;


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {

    if (response != null) {

        mListener.onLoaded(response.getCompanies());

    } else {

        mListener.onError();
    }
}

private String loadJSON(String jsonURL) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(jsonURL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

        response.append(line);
    }

    in.close();
    return response.toString();
}
}
```

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoadJSONTask.Listener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private ListView mListView;

public static final String URL = "url_with_api";

private List<HashMap<String, String>> mAndroidMapList = new ArrayList<>();

private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String KEY_POSTCODE = "postcode";
private static final String KEY_GPS_LAT = "gps_lat";
private static final String KEY_GPS_LNG = "gps_lng";
private static final String KEY_SUMMARY = "summary";
private static final String KEY_WEBSITE = "website";
private static final String KEY_FACEBOOK = "facebook";
private static final String KEY_TWITTER = "twitter";
private static final String KEY_WEBFORM = "webform";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    new LoadJSONTask(this).execute(URL);
}

@Override
public void onLoaded(List<Company> androidList) {

    for (Company android : androidList) {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(KEY_ID, android.getId());
        map.put(KEY_NAME, android.getName());
        map.put(KEY_PHONE, android.getPhone());
        map.put(KEY_ADDRESS, android.getAddress());
        map.put(KEY_POSTCODE, android.getPostcode());
        map.put(KEY_GPS_LAT, android.getGps_lat());
        map.put(KEY_GPS_LNG, android.getGps_lng());
        map.put(KEY_SUMMARY, android.getSummary());
        map.put(KEY_WEBSITE, android.getWebsite());
        map.put(KEY_FACEBOOK, android.getFacebook());
        map.put(KEY_TWITTER, android.getTwitter());
        map.put(KEY_WEBFORM, android.getWebform());
        map.put(KEY_EMAIL, android.getEmail());


        mAndroidMapList.add(map);
    }

    loadListView();
}

@Override
public void onError() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Error !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    Toast.makeText(this, mAndroidMapList.get(i).get(KEY_NAME),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

private void loadListView() {

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mAndroidMapList, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PHONE },
            new int[] { R.id.version,R.id.name, R.id.api });

    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

And the API that I download:

```
[{"id":4,"name":"Name","phone":"Phone","address":"","postcode":"","gps_lat":null,"gps_lng":null,"summary":"Des.","website":"http:","facebook":"","twitter":"","webform":"","email":"Email"},{"id":8,"name":"Name2","phone":"Phone2","address2":"","postcode":"","gps_lat":null,"gps_lng":null,"summary":"Des2.","website":"http:","facebook":"","twitter":"","webform":"","email":"Email"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is a `Company` array not an object `{companies:[]}`

This means that you'll have to deserialize the JSON using something like this:

```
Company[] companies =  new Gson().fromJson(json, Company[].class);
```

Instead of

```
Response response = new Gson().fromJson(json, Response.class);
```

You can change your async task's return type to `List`. Here is what I mean:

```
public class LoadJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Company>> {

    ...

    @Override
    protected List<Company> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ...
        List<Company> companies = new Gson().fromJson(stringResponse, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Company>>(){}.getType());
        return companies;
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Company> companies) {
        if (companies != null) {
            mListener.onLoaded(companies);
        } else {
            mListener.onError();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! but do I just return this in my "doInBackground"? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @kamilsparrow I've updated my answer to address that.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer again! Is this how its supposed to be structured? As I am still having some difficulties :(  I would be super grateful if you could have  a look at your  answer that I updated (as it still underlines my code for some reason) :)
Thank you very much!

Comment: @kamilsparrow I've edited my answer, it should work now. Just replace the `...` with the code from your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. However how do I restore it from the hashmap in "OnLoaded"function? Would you have any idea? As I am not sure how to work with an array of objects. I am grateful for you help!

Comment: @kamilsparrow I don't know what you mean. The `onLoaded` implementation from the `MainActivity` class should work as it is, you don't need to change it.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your patience in replying over my case :) When I return "companies" in "doInBackground" it underlines my returned companies saying that its incompatible types :( I would be very grateful for any help as I have been struggling with it for such a long time and all tutorials online are for databases that start off with an object :) Thank you very much! (I have updated all my code in the question that I have now)

Comment: @kamilsparrow You have to change the `LoadJSONTask` class' definition from `public class LoadJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Response>` to `public class LoadJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Company>>`. You also need to change the `onPostExecute` method first parameter's type to `protected void onPostExecute(List<Company> companies)`. Just like in my answer. Try to understand what all this code is doing, it will be very easy to change it if you understand it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes I am very new to java programming (only did some Python couple years back) and just slowly learn by doing this project :) I have applied the changes however it still says that the return type of "doInBackground" is incompatible (so "Response doInBackground" and "return companies" is underlined). I have analysed the code and tried to find why that is but failed :(

Comment: @kamilsparrow I've edited my question again. I forgot to change the `doInBackground` method's return type. You should probably learn the basics of Java before starting on a project like this.

Comment: Oh Jesus of course it should return my list type rather than Response (I am so stupid for not seeing that!) Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate that! :)

Comment: @kamilsparrow I'm glad I could help. Good luck.